# SUM, SWITCH , OR SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a two columns in SSRS. COL1 and COL2.

My goal is to calculate sum of totals in COL2 based on COL1 values

```
=SUM(Switch(
Fields!COL1.Value="ABC" OR 
Fields!COL1.Value="qwe" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="xyz" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="ijk" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="lmn" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="tyu",Fileds!COL2.Value))
```

I am getting this error if I use the above code:

```
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox78.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC32017] Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is but there's no reason to use **SWITCH** if you only have one condition. This **IIF** should do the same thing:

```
=SUM(IIF(
Fields!COL1.Value="ABC" OR 
Fields!COL1.Value="qwe" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="xyz" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="ijk" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="lmn" OR
Fields!COL1.Value="tyu", Fields!COL2.Value, 0))
```

You did spell **fields** wrong but I assume that was a typo. I haven't used Switch that much, maybe it requires at least two choices?

Comment: Am trying to put my logic in a textbox expression. IIF won't work the way you wrote in SSRS expression.